# How to overcome UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY when installing sentry with npm or curl

Tags: javascript, npm, curl, installation, sentry

[image]

```
curl -sL -k https://sentry.io/get-cli/ | bash
```

As you can see, i am even asking NOT to verify the certificate with -k, but still can't install it.

> This script will automatically install sentry-cli 1.72.2 for you.
> Installation path: /usr/local/bin/sentry-cli curl: (60) SSL
> certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate More
> details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could
> not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this
> situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned
> above.

What can be causing the issue? I have the Same with npm and yarn, see below

```
npm install @sentry/cli
```

> ```
> npm ERR! info sentry-cli Downloading from https://downloads.sentry-cdn.com/sentry-cli/1.72.2/sentry-cli-Windows-x86_64.exe
> npm ERR! Error: Unable to download sentry-cli binary from https://downloads.sentry-cdn.com/sentry-cli/1.72.2/sentry-cli-Windows-x86_64.exe.
> npm ERR! Error code: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
> ```

I tried :

```
npm config set strict-ssl=false 
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

albeit no success

From what i read here it might be a proxy problem. But how do i get to know but i don't understand exactly how to know what is my proxy or the path the my pem certificate

Answer (score 0):

Ok disabling internet security provider during the time of the installation worked for me